# AWS Lambda AppSync Mutation Authorisation Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I used the amplify CLI to setup a GraphQL API and added a function (lambda) to allow for mutation using IAM Auth. I follwed the first section of this [guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js/#create-from-scratch).

However, when testing the lambda function I get the following error.

> Not Authorized to access createSensorData on type Mutation

in detail:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": "{\"data\":{\"createSensorData\":null},\"errors\":[{\"path\":[\"createSensorData\"],\"data\":null,\"errorType\":\"Unauthorized\",\"errorInfo\":null,\"locations\":[{\"line\":3,\"column\":1,\"sourceName\":null}],\"message\":\"Not Authorized to access createSensorData on type Mutation\"}]}"
}
```

The policies were created automatically and the local graphql schema includes the IAM auth:

```
type SensorData @model @auth (
    rules: [
        { allow: private, provider: iam},
        { allow: private, provider: userPools}
    ]
)
{
  
  id: ID!
  device: String!
  dataType: String!
  value: Float!
  timestamp: AWSTimestamp!
  option: String!
}
```

The created schema includes the mutation:

```
type Mutation {
    createSensorData(input: CreateSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
    updateSensorData(input: UpdateSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
    deleteSensorData(input: DeleteSensorDataInput!, condition: ModelSensorDataConditionInput): SensorData
        @aws_iam
@aws_cognito_user_pools
}
```

...letting me infer everything is setup fine.
For completeness, here the code of the lambda function which was created automaticall except the query:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_WEATHERAPP_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT
    API_WEATHERAPP_GRAPHQLAPIIDOUTPUT
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

import crypto from '@aws-crypto/sha256-js';
import { defaultProvider } from '@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node';
import { SignatureV4 } from '@aws-sdk/signature-v4';
import { HttpRequest } from '@aws-sdk/protocol-http';
import { default as fetch, Request } from 'node-fetch';

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_WEATHERAPP_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT;
const AWS_REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'us-east-1';
const { Sha256 } = crypto;

const query = /* GraphQL */ `
mutation {
createSensorData(input: {dataType: "appmutate", device: "mk31", option: "", timestamp: 1592331111, value: 15.11}) {
    id
  }
        }`;

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */

 export const handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: 'appsync',
    sha256: Sha256
  });

  const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      host: endpoint.host
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    path: endpoint.pathname
  });

  const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
  const request = new Request(endpoint, signed);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let body;
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    if (body.errors) statusCode = 400;
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 500;
    body = {
      errors: [
        {
          message: error.message
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    //  Uncomment below to enable CORS requests
    // headers: {
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    //   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
    // }, 
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
};
```

What else could I check? How could one possible debug this error message. I am lost here since days and any help is appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#configure-custom-identity-and-group-claims), did you do `amplify update function` from cli?

Comment: I used amplify add function. Did not update anything yet.